# How do I return a point object aggregated in a another class?

Tags: c++, class, composition, aggregation

How do I return a point object aggregated in a another class? I'm trying to return a point object that's a private member of the quad class. I have written the function and it compiles, but I don't know the correct syntax to call that function.

```
Point Quad::getA()
{
    return Point a;
}


 void Quad::check()
 {
    cout << this->getA();  //will not work
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
class Quad {
  Point a;
  Point getA();
  void check();
};

Point Quad::getA()
{
    return a;
    // or: return Point(); 
    // to return a new point
}

void Quad::check()
{
    cout << getA(); // requires << be overloaded
    // perhaps this is what you want:
    // cout << getA().x;

}
```

Comment: ive tried this yet im getting a the same compiler error" no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << ((Quad*)this)->Quad::getA()"

Comment: @user954004 You need to overload `ostream& <<`. What exactly do you want to print?

Answer (score 0):

`return Point a;` is wrong. You either create a object and then return or have the object created in the return statement itself.

Correct syntax:

```
Point Quad::getA()
{
    Point a;
    return a;
}


Point Quad::getA()
{
    return Point();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside class

```
 Point* p;
```

In GetA() function.

```
if (p== null) {
   p= new Point();
 }
return p;
```

Returning a pointer would be a better solution. Maintaining a single pointer throughout the lifetime of the program would make it easier for the developer to properly destroy the same. For reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Sorry my bad. Had this in the mind but conveyed it wrong.

Comment: This returns Point* not a Point. It's usually better to pass in a pointer which has already been created for the function to manipulate, otherwise it's easy to forget that this object will need to be deleted later.